# How to wrap an image in tag based on file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with various images tapered throughout.

I would like to use jQuery to find those that use video.jpg and wrap those images in a new `<div>`:

```
<img src="/images/thumb1.jpg" alt="no div" />
<img src="/images/video.jpg" alt="wrap me" />
<img src="/images/thumb2.jpg" alt="no div" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Made this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxBA7/) for you.

This should work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = $('[src="/images/video.jpg"]');
    images.each(function() {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I modify this to work regardless of the image's path?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
$("img[src$=video.jpg]").wrap("<div></div>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('img[src=*"video.jpg"]').wrap('<div></div>');
```